# Django inlines, how i know which was edited?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

i would like to know , how ill know which inlines forms was edited?

In my case i want to save a custom value for every inlines form when was edited, so, how i know how much was edited or which one?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps you can compare the contents of it with what has been saved into the database? Or add hidden checkbox field to each inline, which will be set to different value, when inline has been edited?

Comment: i fixed :) , django the best thing jeje